# How to Map Sub Domain Methods to Original Domain's Method in CodeIgniter 2.4

Tags: php, subdomain, codeigniter-2

My site is "www.domain.com" based on codeigniter framework. Recently I thought of creating mobile version of site and wanted to create subdomain "m.domain.com"

For this I have a setup like this:

htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for mobile site I have controller called "mobile"

routes.php

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
case 'm.domain.com':
$route['default_controller'] = "mobile";
break;
default:
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
break;
}
```

Also I have setup wildcard subdomain for this to work.

when I access "m.domain.com" it is handled by "www.domain.com/mobile". That's intended and working fine.

Now I wanted to add another controller function inside mobile called "list"

so I have

```
controller mobile
-> index()
-> list()
```

I was thinking that when I access "m.domain.com/list" it will be mapped to "www.domain.com/mobile/list" but that is not the case. Instead I am getting 404 error.

My intention is to call "list()" as mentioned above or via AJAX, which I found impossible at this point.

My question is how to map that.

Comment: use Codeigniter `route` function. (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using JSONP instead.

Getting JSONP data by calling "www.domain.com/mobile/list" from "m.domain.com", I was able to get around this problem.

I still wonder if there is codeigniter specific way of doing this as I intended.

Other ideas are welcome too.

Thanks anyway